# User reaction on different form of advertisements

Tags: user-research, advertisement

I am planning of creating a free software in upcoming months. I also wants to monetize my advertise my software by different forms of advertisements. These are:

A) **PPC advertisement on web site** : This will be much like [Google Adsense](http://www.google.com/AdSense) for websites

B) **PPC advertisement on software downloader** : This will be much like [Cnet spotinstall](http://upload.cnet.com/8301-21_5-57459963-9978525.html) and one will display one or two ads during the software download.

C) **Advertising through software module** This will be much like [OpenCandy](http://www.opencandy.com).

No, more ads will be displayed during software running. So, my question is how the user will react to these ads.

- Will the user feel them annoying? Does this make my software a adware?
- Are chances are high that user will abort download be seeing ads in the download manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds great, as the user's use of your software will not be interrupted by advertisements.But, there are definitely a few things you should keep in mind, to have a healthy, happy consumer-base.

> A) PPC Advertisement on Website

Things to keep in mind are that these will not be very profitable as many users have adblock enabled, but there are definitely things you should remember for people who don't have these ads.

1. Avoid interrupting your users experience. Examples being an "intermission page" or a "landing page" or a "interstitial page" that is an advertisement, that puts obstacles between the user and the content. Another good example of a bad thing would be to have a lightbox of an advertisement come up.
2. Do not confuse or attack users with advertisements. Examples being videos that auto-play, interactive flash "games" that are literally scam/spam, autoplaying-audio. All of these confuse users by taking a good web-design, and throwing random movement everywhere, that really ruins the website. Or when you go on a website and there are 10 different videos playing, this can really attack and slow down your site for users with slower computers, and slower internet connections. And I can not even begin to explain how irritating it is to have an audio-ad playing while trying to browse a website.
3. Generally try to avoid ads that are reliant on flash, these will make your website extremely vulnerable,

> C) Advertising through software Module

1. DO NOT TRY TO TRICK YOUR USERS INTO INSTALLING SOFTWARE. This is okay to have software module installs, but do not have tricky terms like "I accept the terms and agreements of installing "Insert Software", and having terms and stuff above it, this tricks the user. This will only create a distrust between you and your user.

Comment: Actually I planning of using either 1 or 2 or 3 form of advertisement which is more profitable and user-friendly. You have not tell about Ads on software downloader. How the user reacts to them. Does the user seeing the ad will think the program as a adware?

Comment: I think what I said about C applies to  B. If you're honest with your users about installing the software it's okay, but if you are clear with your users."Hey I'm installing something on you're computer to support me, is that okay?" and you have a picture of the software on top of the checkbox to make it clear when somebody is just clicking next, next, next.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, user will not be happy of any advertisement. But if he really need your software he will download it anyways. You task is to monetize - so use each of advertisements you've mentioned above only choosing good providers of these services.

But, if you afraid that advertisements make your users feel uncomfortable, maybe you should change your monetizing scheme and try to achieve more installation by making download as simple as possible. If your software is really good you'll promote yourself and possibly you'll obtain more benefits from this.